# How can I select multiple columns while setting one of them as DISTINCT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 6 columns and I want to select data from them while fixing one column as distinct

```
Column1 |Column2         |Column3       |Column4     |Column5     |Column6
--------|----------------|--------------|------------|------------|-------
 A      |267             |2364          |001         |345.000000  |22
 B      |267             |2364          |001         |700.000000  |22
 C      |267             |2364          |001         |345.000000  |22
 D      |267             |2364          |001         |1200.000000 |22
 E      |267             |2364          |001         |1350.000000 |22
 F      |267             |2364          |001         |345.000000  |22
 A      |267             |2364          |002         |270.000000  |22
 B      |267             |2364          |002         |2300.000000 |22
 C      |267             |2364          |002         |270.000000  |22
```

the Display should be the following:

```
Column1 |Column2         |Column3       |Column4     |Column5       |Column6
--------|----------------|--------------|------------|--------------|-------
A       |267.000000     |2364.000000      |001        |345.000000   |22
B       |267.000000     |2364.000000      |001        |700.000000   |22
C       |267.000000     |2364.000000      |001        |345.000000   |22
D       |267.000000     |2364.000000      |001        |1200.000000  |22
E       |267.000000     |2364.000000      |001        |1350.000000  |22
F       |267.000000     |2364.000000      |001        |345.000000   |22
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ROW_NUMBER` and `TOP`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5, Column6
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Column1, Column2, Column3 ORDER BY Column4);
```

But this assumes that the second and third column are part of what defines a "group" in your expected result set.  If instead only `Column1` decides that, then use this version:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5, Column6
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Column1 ORDER BY Column4);
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though I like Tim's `TOP 1 WITH TIES` (+1)  It should be pointed out that a sub-query or CTE would be a nudge more performant.  Especially if you have a large table... small tables, any difference would be in-perceivable.

Your desired DISTINCT is no clear, so my `Partition By` and `Order By` is a guess

**Example**

```
 Select *
  From (
         Select *
               ,RN = row_number() over (Partition By Column1 Order By Column4)
          From  YourTable
       ) A
  Where RN = 1
```